# How can I read my XML data from my XML file in Jersey client?

Tags: java, xml, jersey-client

The following snippet of code stores a simple data in `input` and passes that variable as a POST request to the server.

```
String input = “{\”singer\”:\”Metallica\”,\”title\”:\”Fade To Black\”}”;
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(“application/json”)
  .post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

My objective is to:

1. store my XML data in a XML file
2. pass that XML data through my XML file to the server as a POST request

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post");
        String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

I tried below given code but it is not working.

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(“MediaType.APPLICATION_XML”)
  .entity(new File(“C:\\MyXml.xml”)
  .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

How I can read my XML data from my XML file in Jersey client? And transfer that XML data to server as a POST request in order to get a correct response from server?

Comment: "but it is not working" : can you tell us what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It is not giving any error because there is no error in code. But it is unable to read the data from the xml file. I have one XML file in which details of column is written when i will pass that XML file in the server as a POST request. It will create a column in my DATABASE. Because it is unable to read the data from XML file that's why no column is created in the DATABASE.